# Calculating the molar mass of a solute from freezing point

Tags: solubility, solutions, concentration

> A $\pu{4.305 g}$ sample of a nonelectrolyte is dissolved in $\pu{105 g}$ of water. The solution freezes at $\pu{-1.23^\circ C}$. Calculate the molar mass of the solute. $k_f$ for water is $\pu{1.86 C/m}$.

My steps:

$$1.23 = 1.86 \times \frac{x}{1.05},$$

where $x = y / 4.305$.

$$0.66 = \frac{x}{1.05}$$
$$x = 0.69$$
$$0.69 = y / 4.305$$
$$y = \pu{2.989 g}$$

But I know this is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

The [freezing point depression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing_point_depression) is based on the molal concentration (moles of solute per kg of solvent).

$$\Delta T_f = -k_f \cdot m$$

You know the freezing point depression of the solution and the cryoscopic constant, so you can calculate the molality:

$$m = -\dfrac{\Delta T_f}{k_f}=-\dfrac{\pu{-1.23 ^\circ C}}{1.86 \frac{\textrm{kg}\cdot ^\circ \text{C}}{\textrm{mol}}}=\pu{0.66 molal}$$

Since molality is the number of moles of solute divided by the mass of the solvent in kg, you can calculate the moles of the solute:

$$n_\textrm{solute}= \pu{0.66 m} \cdot \pu{ 0.105 kg}= \ ...$$

Divide your mass of solute by the moles of solute and you will get the molar mass (and not 2.989 g).